# Generate Hexagon within Hexagon and show only certain connections

Tags: graphs-and-networks

[image: Hexagon inside Hexagon]

How can I generate the hexagons shown?

I'd like to add names to all the disks and the colored links.

And rotate the whole thing by 30 degrees.

Answer (score 9):

```
coords = N @ Join[CirclePoints[{4, 0}, 6], CirclePoints[{2, Pi/6}, 6]]; 

nng = IndexGraph @ NearestNeighborGraph[coords, VertexLabels -> "Index"]
```

[image]

Shrink the vertex coordinates of outer ring towards the center:

```
nng2 = IndexGraph @ NearestNeighborGraph[coords, VertexLabels -> "Index", 
   VertexCoordinates -> MapAt[#/4 &, coords, {;; 6}]]
```

[image]

and add the missing edges:

```
edgeadd = UndirectedEdge[#, # + 3] & /@ Range[3];

nng2 = EdgeAdd[nng2, edgeadd]
```

[image]

Add desired styling options using [`SetProperty`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetProperty.html) :

```
SetProperty[nng2, 
  {VertexSize -> Alternatives @@ Range[6] -> Medium, 
   VertexStyle -> Alternatives @@ Range[6] -> Red, 
   EdgeStyle -> Thread[edgeadd -> 
      (Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], ColorData[97]@#] & /@ Range[Length@edgeadd])]}]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can also use [`Annotate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annotate.html) instead of `SetProperty` if you have version 12.1+.

Comment: Excellent. This is what Wolfram should do - develop AI to answer such questions on the fly. It'll probably take me 5+ years to reach that level.

Answer (score 6):

Create two sets of 6 points on a circle of radius 1/2 and radius 1:

```
vcoords = Join[CirclePoints[{1/2, 0}, 6], CirclePoints[{1, Pi/6}, 6]];
```

Two points in `vcoords` are connected if their distance is 1 or `Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[3]]/2`:

```
relation = Chop[EuclideanDistance[##] - Sqrt[5. - 2 Sqrt[3]]/2] == 0. || 
    EuclideanDistance[##] == 1 &;
```

Use [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) with `relation` and `vcoords`:

```
rg = IndexGraph@RelationGraph[relation, vcoords , VertexCoordinates -> vcoords ]
```

[image]

Add options to style/annotate vertices and edges as desired:

```
options = {ImageSize -> 400,
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Index", Center],
   VertexStyle -> {_ -> Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], White], 
      Alternatives @@ Range[6] -> Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], Orange]}, 
   VertexSize -> {_ -> Medium, Alternatives @@ Range[6] -> .25}, 
   PlotTheme -> "ThickEdge", 
   EdgeStyle -> {_ -> Gray, UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] /; Max[{a, b}] <= 6 :> 
     Directive[ColorData[97] @ Min[{a, b}], Thickness[.1], CapForm["Round"]]}};

Graph[rg, options]
```

[image]

**Update:** ***to overcome the limitation "Two points in vcoords are connected if their distance is 1 or `Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[3]]/2`":***

we can define a function that takes as input the scaling factor for the coordinates of the first 6 vertices:

```
ClearAll[rG]
rG[scale_: 1, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Graph[IndexGraph @
    RelationGraph[relation, vcoords, 
       VertexCoordinates -> MapAt[scale # &, vcoords, {;; 6}]],
    opts];
```

***Examples:***

```
rG[]
```

[image]

Scale the inner vertex coordinates by 3/2:

```
rG[3/2]
```

[image]

Add `options` to get the desired look:

```
Grid[{rG[#, ImageSize -> 300, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[PromptForm[scale, #], 18, Black]] & /@ {.5, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 3}, 
  rG[#, ImageSize -> 300, options] & /@ {.5, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty cool. Is there a way to overcome the limitation "Two points in vcoords are connected if their distance is 1 or Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[3]]/2"?

Comment: @Gannicus, please see the update.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way to use `RelationGraph`:

```
relationB = And[#2 == # - 6 || #2 == # - 5 || Mod[# + 1, 12, 1] == #2, # >= 7] ||
     And[#2 == # + 3, #2 <= 6] &;

vertexcoordinates = Join[#, 2 RotationTransform[Pi/6]@#] &@CirclePoints[6];

RelationGraph[relationB, Range[12],
 DirectedEdges -> False, 
 VertexCoordinates -> vertexcoordinates]
```

[image]

```
options = {ImageSize -> 400,
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
   VertexStyle -> {_ -> Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], White],
     Alternatives @@ Range[6] -> Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], Orange]},
   VertexSize -> {_ -> Medium, Alternatives @@ Range[6] -> .25},
   PlotTheme -> "ThickEdge",
   EdgeStyle -> {_ -> Directive[Opacity[.3], Black],
     UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] /; Max[{a, b}] <= 6 :>
      Directive[Opacity[.7], {Red, Green, Blue}[[Min[{a, b}]]], 
       Thickness[.1], CapForm["Round"]]}};

RelationGraph[relationB, Range[12],
 DirectedEdges -> False, 
 VertexCoordinates -> vertexcoordinates, 
 options]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. If you keep going, you

Answer (score 1):

Start with this as an example

```
Graphics[{
  Green,Line[{{Cos[0Degree],Sin[0Degree]},{Cos[180Degree],Sin[180Degree]}}],
  Red,Line[{{Cos[60Degree],Sin[60Degree]},{Cos[240Degree],Sin[240Degree]}}],
  Black,Line[Table[{2*Cos[t],2*Sin[t]},{t,30 Degree,390Degree,60Degree}]],
  Text["x",{Cos[0]+1/4,Sin[0]+1/4}],
  Text["y",{2Cos[30Degree]+1/4,2Sin[30Degree]+1/4}],
  Gray,Table[{Disk[{2*Cos[t],2*Sin[t]},1/8]},{t,30 Degree,330Degree,60Degree}],
  Orange,Table[{Disk[{Cos[t],Sin[t]},1/4]},{t,0 Degree,300 Degree,60 Degree}]}]
```

Then you can add additional lines and colors and text and add 30 Degree to all the angles to rotate your figure.

Comment: the lines from the outer hexagon to the orange disks are missing

Comment: Yes. That was exactly why I wrote that last sentence, "Then you can add additional lines and..." This was an example that showed you how to do each of the kinds of things that you wrote that you wanted. You need to use that example to finish your project, and hopefully learn enough in the process that you will be able to apply that to your next project and your next and ...

Comment: Bottom line - you did not answer the entire question

Comment: There is another line below your bottom line where some people here feel this is not a free programming service. Those people will often ask "What have you already tried?" when someone posts a request for a code with no indication that they have made an effort on their own. I do understand that some new users want a magic "do what I mean button" and when you push it Mathematica will give you a solution, even if you haven't explained your problem or have made mistakes. Thus far nobody has shown any way to do that other than by invoking "go get bright grad student to do it for you." Good Luck.

Comment: Yet again: Don't bother to react to a question if you don't want to answer it

Comment: Great answer! It is often better to learn from such things, rather than to request such learning be done for you. Here, you’ve taught us how to fish. Thanks!